# is it possible to run IE8 on ubuntu via selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu-14.04

I can run IE on ubuntu with playOnlinux manually.
How do you think is it possible to run it with Selenium WebDriver?

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse--935095095/testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$100(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.build(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
    at com.example.fw.ApplicationManager.<init>(ApplicationManager.java:70)
    at
```

Which libraries should I install exactly?

thanks

Comment: IE on Linux? Seems like an awful idea in the first place.

Comment: what if I need to test something under IE?

Comment: I suspect you'll need a Selenium server running under Wine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this not gonna work.

Instead, automate IE on a real windows machine, or use a *standalone selenium server*: either your own, or at [`BrowserStack`](http://www.browserstack.com/) or [`Saucelabs`](https://saucelabs.com/).

Comment: I've used this solution to success, if not to great debugging pain